# PHP: output count()

Tags: php, sql

How do i work with the COUNT()

```
$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT COUNT() FROM discos_events e INNER JOIN discos_events_guests eg ON (e.ID = eg.eID) INNER JOIN users u ON (eg.uID = u.id) WHERE e.dID =:id");
$sql->bindValue(":id", $cID);

$sql->execute();
```

...then what? `echo $sql["count"];` ? to output the count?

Comment: Just replace your query with if ($year < 1980) echo "ERROR: too many events found"; else echo "0"; ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an alias name for your `COUNT()` column:

```
$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT COUNT() AS num_events FROM discos_events e INNER JOIN discos_events_guests eg ON (e.ID = eg.eID) INNER JOIN users u ON (eg.uID = u.id) WHERE e.dID =:id");
$sql->bindValue(":id", $cID);

// Fetch the results and then access the alias
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetch();
echo $result['num_events'];
```

Comment: If i need to $sql->execute(); and then $sql->fetch(); and then echo $sql['num_events']; why do they say this is faster than echo $sql->rowCount(); ?

Comment: @Karem If you only need the number of returned rows, then no need to `fetch()`.  But if you're selecting multiple columns with a `COUNT()` aggregate you need to `fetch()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777978/sql-php-counting-average-male-females , caffeins answer says COUNT() function is way faster than executing full query and then fetching it with rowCount(). Is he wrong?

Comment: @Karem I see the confusion.  The answerer over there was stating that it's faster to `SELECT COUNT()` than to select all the individual columns and then determine the `rowCount()` even though you don't have to fetch to get the `rowCount()`.  It is the `COUNT()` query that runs faster, not that it is faster/easier to code.  You still have to fetch the `COUNT()` but the query itself will run much more quickly in the database

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute() the query, so:

```
$result = $sql->execute(array('id' => $cId)); // just to illustrate that you can use this instead of bindParam
if ($result) {
    $row = $sql->fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after execute, you have to `store_result()` and `fetch()`
As @Michael suggests, you may alias the count(), to get it in more reatable form.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to assign the count value to a name, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT() n FROM discos_events ...
```

Then you can reference the name `n` in your PHP array:

```
echo $sql["n"];
```

You can, of course, call it 'count' or any other name you prefer, but be careful of using names which are reserved words in SQL (such as 'count'). If you want to give it a reserved name, you need to enclose it in backtick characters so that SQL recognises that it's a name you want to use rather than its own reserved word.